# service receiving Null values in an intent

Tags: android, android-intent, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm starting a service from the BroadcastReceiver and sending some values from BroadcastReceiver to the service. When I'm trying to retrieve those values in the service, It's giving me null value.

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance!

starting service from broadcast-

```
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, LatestCallService.class);
    intent.putExtra("from","Internet");
    context.startService(serviceIntent);
```

retrieving value in service but giving Null-

```
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    super.onStart(intent, startId);
    String a= intent.getStringExtra("from");
    Toast.makeText(this, " Name : "+a, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: ur code looks fine , did u add a `breakpoint` and check ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "Event", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
        intent.putExtra("check","done");
        context.startService(intent);
    }
```

Use the Intent from onReceive method

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked, your solution saved my lot of time, but can you tell me why we used the same intent which we got from the broadcast receiver?

Answer (score 0):

while getting intent put code in onBind() method
  Service:
    @Override
     public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
      mTourName = intent.getStringExtra("tour_name");
      return mBinder;
      }

try this .

Comment: I tried and this time the Toast is also not coming.